# WebView, WebViewClient and links

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, webviewclient

Do I need to implement my own WebViewClient in order for my WebView to handle common links like geo:, tel: and mailto:?

Can't the WebView handle it on it's own?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open web pages in your application and you want to customize it, like you want to add button on the webpage then you have to implement your own WebViewClient class in your class otherwise it will open default browser of your devise/emulator and then you can not do anything on it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I agree with rahul. If you want to have control over the flow of your webview like which URLs are allowed and which are disallowed, when the loading of a page started and finished etc. then you need to have implement your webview client.